# Is it possible for a PHP command line script to update itself and restart with new code?

Tags: php, include

Many moons ago when I was getting started in programming, I coded a MUD (Multi User Dungeon - text based 'MMO' for back before the internet had pictures, for all you youngins!). It was written in C and I learned a ton, and one of the coolest things I learned while coding that mud was making the individual areas of code compiled as linked libraries (I believe thats what they are called? Its been a long time since I coded in C) and I was able to dynamically update/change the code of the game without ever having to shut it down/reboot it. Unlink the old library, move the new one in place, relink, turn that functionality back on.

Present day: I have a PHP command line script I have running that handles some server tasks. Before the lecture, yes, I know it's not the best/most efficient language to do this in. But due to certain factors, it's the language its done in right now.

The script I'm running actually runs on 4 different servers, and when it starts, there is a calling script that runs a wget to get the updated 'core' code from the main server, includes it, then runs it. Here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php
  echo "Grabbing latest code...\n";
  `wget -N http://blahblahblah.php`;
  `wget -N http://blahblahothercode.php`;

  include('blahblahblah.php');
?>
```

So my question - is it possible to, while it's running, have it update it's own code and reload itself? My current solution is for it to exit() after using a shell 'at' command to restart itself. Clunky, but it could accomplish the goal.

The problem there is when the script starts, it grabs an encryption key from stdin that must be typed in when the script starts. I don't ever want that key saved to disk anywhere (I don't want the key saved to a temp file to be read back in, or in any command history for 'at'). IDEALLY, I'd like to leave the key in memory and just 'replace' the running code. If thats even possible with PHP.

When we eventually redo this in C++ we have the option of libraries, but for now, is there any way to accomplish that in PHP?

Just had a thought right before I hit submit... when PHP hits an include command, does it do the include once when it runs, or will it run the include every time it sees it? That might be an option if I loop around an include...?

Comment: Self-mutating code...this is how the machines will take over the world.

Comment: An include is executed once, when it is first encountered, so looping over an include statement will only actually execute the include file once, and thereafter it will execute the code that was included each iteration

Comment: There is only 1 way, and it's called process supervising. You fork, having your parent process contain that info about the encr. key (in a variable). Now the fun part - the child is the running code. Now what you do - you need to detect changes on files (event loop, stat() with polling - whatever you can use). Once you detect the change occurred in the child process, it kills itself (exit, die, whatever). Now we're back to parent - parent receives the signal that its child exited. You boot it back again (yes, fork again). Repeat forever. However, your key is in memory and can be looked up so..

Comment: Thats an interesting idea. I was considering namespaces or wrapping everything in a class if it was possible to redefine those. Forking a child may be easier. The reason I want to do this is if I make a minor change, I need to remote into 4 different machines, kill the process, restart it, and type the key in. PITA. As for the key in memory - no avoiding that. My concern is physical theft of the server or data theft of the drive contents. Cant steal it without unplugging it, and can't get the key if its not on the disk.

Comment: NB: Thats the perfect solution. Just ran a small test. Set a variable, then, looped around a fork. The child code was an include and then an exit(). After the fork code I had a 'press enter to continue' line. Ran it, it ran the include. While it was waiting for enter, I changed the included file. Pressed enter. It ran the new/changed code. Perfect. Can you mark a comment as an answer here? I'm a noob here at stackoverflow! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comment (copy/pasting):

There is only 1 way, and it's called process supervising. You fork, having your parent process contain that info about the encr. key (in a variable). Now the fun part - the child is the running code. Now what you do - you need to detect changes on files (event loop, stat() with polling - whatever you can use). Once you detect the change occurred in the child process, it kills itself (exit, die, whatever). Now we're back to parent - parent receives the signal that its child exited. You boot it back again (yes, fork again). Repeat forever. However, your key is in memory and can be looked up so.

Update: I've been using this approach for a while, however I also use LibEV and PHP extension to work with it in order to react to stat events (file changes). You can take a look at the extension here: https://github.com/m4rw3r/php-libev

Answer (score 0):

There is a way, but it probably won't be pretty. The main problem is that most things (functions, classes, etc) in PHP are named and once defined, cannot be redefined.

You can get around that by using only anonymous functions and objects; that way you can simply include a module again and it will simply override the old anonymous functions with the new ones. You'll get something that looks a lot like LUA or JavaScript code.

But your code probably isn't built for that, so you'd pretty much lose must of your work.

Maybe a better solution for an existing project would be to split the program in two parts, and run an update program first that will fetch the latest code and then starts the actual program, passing along the key as it boots it? Unless you want to update the program while it's already running, anyway.

Comment: Well what I had considered as I was driving about today was to have the main program load the includes, get the key, then loop the includes until necessary to 'reboot' then re-load the includes, that way they key and any other relevant variables stay in memory, But without being able to redefine functions that may be an issue. Looking at namespaces, though, all 'global' variables would need to be outside that. (Global as in vars passed to multiple functions)

Answer (score 0):

You can always use

```
eval('?>' . file_get_contents('updated.php') . '<?php ');
```

I would avoid this ugly approach though.

Cheers.

Comment: Yeah. I thought eval but even I think thats a bad idea ;)